# Нахождение кадра в видеоклипе

Tags: python, видео

- Есть видеоклип около 3 минут длиной `(1)`.
- Есть нарезка кадров из этого клипа `(2)`.

Надо установить точное соответствие: какой кадр из `(1) = кадр из (2)`.

Таких клипов\нарезок довольно много, поэтому разбивать видос `(1)` на многотысячную кучу кадров, и затем сравнивать по одному с кадрами из `(2)` не вариант. Надо делать на лету.

Какие есть варианты? Подойдёт ли здесь `cv2.VideoCapture()`?
ЯП python

Comment: Предоставьте, пожалуйста, имеющийся код Вашей программы.

Comment: Нет никакой программы, и кода я тоже не прошу)) Нужна подсказка 'какие инструменты решают эту задачу'.

Comment: Задача чрезвычайно размыта. Например неясно: 1. Как представлены кадры; 2. Каким образом и откуда идёт их считывание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. достать кадры из видеопотока

   ```
   reader = imageio.get_reader(pathToVideo)
   arr = self.reader.get_data(nOfFrameOfVideo) # arr потому что из 
                                               # картинки надо сделать 
                                               # массив
   ```
2. Из картинки для сравнения надо тоже сделать массив. Передать два массива `(img1, img2)` в функцию ниже.
3. Функция для сравнения двух картинок

   ```
     def compareImages(self, img1, img2):
         diff = img1 - img2              # поэлементная разница 
         norm1 = sum(abs(diff))          # сумма поэлементной разницы 
         norm2 = norm(diff.ravel(), 0)   
         return (round(norm1/self.size, 3),
                 round(norm2*1.0/self.size, 3))
   ```